# how to convert an if-else statement to a linear programming constraint in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have two variables `E[i]` and `Y[i]`, where `E` is a continuous variable and `Y` is binary.So the condition is:

```
if E[i] <= rmin:
        Y[i]==1
    else:
        Y[i]==0
```

How do I convert this `if-else` loop to linear constraint using Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "linear constraint"? Do you have a library in mind? Aside: an `if` statement is not a loop.

Comment: You could simply write `Y[i] = E[i] <= min`, unless there is some context where you *really* need to differentiate between a `bool` and an `int`. (As it is, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `True` and `False` are literally the values 1 and 0, respectively, by different names.)

Comment: Linear constraint: A constraint in linear programming

Comment: Yes, but Python doesn't have a concept of linear constraints, so it's not clear what you are looking to create.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to solve a mixed integer linear programming optimization problem. I am using mip library. This is an example of how I write a constraint for this library.

Comment: model += E[i] >= rmin

Comment: Since it is optimization. i think I cannot write E[i]=Y[i]

Comment: Because both are two different variable types as initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify a little, let `E'[i] = E[i] - rmin`.

You want to express `Y[i] = 1 if E'[i] <= 0, and 0 otherwise`.

If `E'` is (strictly) bounded by some number `c`, then it's easy: `Y[i] > -E'[i]/c` and `Y[i] < E'[i]/c`.

Otherwise I think you can't do it just using a constraint, but you can if you can use the maximization clause and slack variables. You can write `k = max(min(E'[i], 0.5), -0.5)`, `Y[i] > -k`, `Y[i] < k`, and then use standard LP tricks to express the `max` and `min`.

Comment: The E' in my case is not strictly bounded to some number. I think I should use the maximization clause but I am not able to understand it much from this comment. Could you share a link? What is k here?

Comment: @sm_050 did you find anything related?